# Как сделать взаимодействие между пользователями в Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Делаю веб приложение, которое предоставляет возможность соревноваться в прохождении викторины. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы у каждого пользователя загружался очередной вопрос, если кто-то из них уже ответил правильно. У меня совершенно нет идей, как сделать взаимодействие между пользователями. Полагаю, что должен быть создан компонент, который обращается к view, чтобы загрузить страницу всем пользователям, а view перед этим обращается к нему, чтобы дать сигнал к переменам. Предложите пожалуйста варианты решений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для етого вы можете использовать Websocket, в Django ecть Channels https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

В кратце вы загружаете страницу и подписываетесь на websocket канал и уже по каналу сможете отправлять данные с сервера на клиент в любое время. Ибо без етого вы не можете менять содержимое страницы в браузере без запроса к серверу.

Когда кто-то ответит то вы сможете по каналу отправить в браузер другого игрока следующий вопрос, а потом наоборот.

Пытался как можно проще написать ответ, что бы вы поняли куда вам копать.